# Перебор xml и клонирование

Tags: php

Есть xml вида

```
<Properties>
   <Property>
     <id>...</id>
   </Property>
</Properties>
```

Подгружаю его через simplexml_load_file и перебираю через foreach. Внутри цикла проверяю по условию id и хочу клонировать целиком объект Property в новый DOMDocument()

```
    $root = $doc->createElement("Properties");
    $doc->appendChild($root);
    foreach ($xml as $row) {
      if ($row->id == что-то) {
      // Клонируем целиком Property в $doc
      } 
    }
```

Вопрос - Как это правильно сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гуглив часами на пролет пришел к такому варианту. Для меня то, что нужно. Может кому пригодится

```
                $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
                $fragment->appendXML($row->asXML());
                $doc->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);
```